# how to set the database file location that my app will use ?

Tags: android

I want to set the location of the database file that i will use on my app. 
I want to define that this file will be at some folder that i create on the disk and not on the default location

How to do it ?

Comment: Probably would start by reading the documentation of Databases and how they are created.

Comment: I rad the documentation ! and i know that there are some SQLitebaseConfiguration file that get path on his first parameter - but i can't find a way to config this path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "database.db3"), null)`, whereas the String in new File() is the path to your database. But it's higly recommended to store it in the specified path, not *somewhere*